# laravel site map and casting to xml

Tags: laravel, seo, sitemap

I have written a sitemap with the help of https://laravel-news.com/laravel-sitemap

here is my index :

```
public function siteMap(  )
{
    $news=News::orderBy('time','desc')->where('time','<',time())->where('showview',1)->first();
    $categories = Cat::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();
    $games = Game::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();
    $genres = Genre::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();
    $movies = Movie::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();
    $platforms = Platform::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->first();

    return response()->view('siteMap.siteMap', [

        'news'          =>  $news,
        'categories'    =>  $categories,
        'games'         =>  $games,
        'genres'        =>  $genres,
        'movies'        =>  $movies,
        'platforms'     =>  $platforms

    ])->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

and my blade  :

```
<?php

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

```
{{-- site map for posts --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc> //url /{{ $news->id }}/{{ $news->title }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c',$news->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>

{{-- sitemap for categories --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc>//url/{{ $categories->id }}/{{ $categories->name }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c',  $categories->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>

{{-- sitemap for games profile --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc>//url/profiles/games/{{ $games->id }}/{{ $games->name }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c', (integer) $games->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>

{{-- sitemap for genres profile --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc>//url/{{ $genres->id }}/{{ $genres->name }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c',  $genres->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>

{{-- sitemap for movie profile --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc>//url/{{ $movies->id }}/{{ $movies->name }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c',  (integer) $movies->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>

{{-- sitemap for platforms profile --}}
<sitemap>
    <loc>//url/{{ $platforms->id }}/{{ $platforms->name }}</loc>
    <lastmod>{{ date('c', (integer) $platforms->time) }}</lastmod>
</sitemap>
```

after uploading on host and using google webmaster i get below error :

Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.

thanks for your help !

Comment: Make sure the route has xml as the extension `Route::get('sitemap.xml'...`. Don't forget the sitemapindex `<sitemapindex...`. You can also check the formatting by viewing the browser source to make sure it looks correct.

Comment: Sidenote, you can use `{!! !!}` instead of `<?php echo ...` to output HTML into a `.blade.php` file. Or just write it as plain HTML; shouldn't need PHP tags for that.

Comment: @aynber after checking browser I post this question and pretty sure the problem is not the routes . 
Thanks

Comment: @Amir_Jani did you fix this? I'm getting the same error from google search console while splitting my sitemaps with sitemapindex. I haven't add response `text/xml` yet, cause the old sitemap action didn't have it.

Comment: @KeitelDOG I don't remember how I fixed this one, but I've got my answer from ericlbarnes in laracast https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/seo-with-laravel-and-cast-to-xml

Comment: @Amir_Jani thank you. I've fixed it, and i think it was more like a cache problem may be in the new Google Search Console. It was recommended to delete the sitemap first before submitting again. So what I did was to delete it, and submit a new sitemap uri cause I changed it's structure for sitemapindex. And it worked.